# Прошу помощи urlpatterns в Django 2

Tags: python, django

В django 2 вместо url используется path.

Суть вопроса. Как с помощью path сделать запрос по виду ***domain.test/topic/1***

C помощью url это делается вот так:
`url(r'^topic/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', topic, name='topic')`

В views вместе с request принимаем pk и все работает.

Как это реализовать с помощтю path? И что нужно передать в views.

PS Только начинаю изучать Python и django.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import TopicPage

urlpatterns = [
    path('topic/<slug:title>/<int:id>/', TopicPage.as_view(), name='topic-page'),
]
```

`<slug:title>` - ожидается строка в формате `slug`
`<int:id>` - ожидается положительное число
Ещё можно указать `str`, `uuid` и др.

Во views.py можете получать значения `title` и `id` из словаря `kwargs`.

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views.generic import View

    class TopicPage(View):
    TEMPLATES = 'someApp/topic-page.html'
        def get(self, *args, **kwargs):
            data = {}
            data['id'] = kwargs.get('id')
            data['title'] = kwargs.get('title')
            return render(self.request, self.TEMPLATES, context=data)
```

А вообще вы можете использовать `re_path` вместо `path`, он аналогичен url в Django ver. < 2.0

Comment: Извените меня за мое невежество, но как отрендерить страницу по полученному URL? Что передать в `render(request, 'blog/topic.html')`...так как по полученному урлу, а он корректен, выдается ошибка "The current path, topic/1/, didn't match any of these. "

Comment: Подкорректировал ответ. `TEMPLATES ` - переменная в которой указывается шаблон который будет рендериться. В него передаются данные `context=data` (т.е. получить в шаблоне данные можете так `{{title}} {{id}}`).